# First ruby and postgreSql application - getting could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, postgresql

> Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS X Lion

Followed several posts on SO about this topic. Neither helped.

Trying to run my **first** rails and postgreSQL app here.

Following this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

When I do:

```
"rake db:create"
```

I get:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server
>   running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Some facts:

Not sure what /tmp/ is it referring to but, if it is the one from root, then:

1)
Permissions:

drwxrwxrwx   11 root  wheel   374B Jan  4 17:33 tmp

2)
Also, I see no file .s.PGSQL.5432.

3)
I've tried to force the socket location by adding to database.yml the following:

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: testblog_development
    pool: 5
    username: blog
    password:
    socket: /var/pgsql_socket # <-- this line
```

(it stills shows me the same error with the /tmp/ path).

4) When I do, `which postgres` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/postgres 
(I've used homebrew installation)
```

5) When I do: `brew info postgres` I get:

> postgresql: stable 9.2.2 http://www.postgresql.org/ Depends on:
>   readline, ossp-uuid Conflicts with: postgres-xc
>   /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.2 (2819 files, 39M) *
>   https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb

and other bunch of information.

Comment: My current status - http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png
@MEM did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

That seems to me like the server isn't running. Do you see anything when you run `ps aux | grep postgres` from the command line? If all you see is something along the lines of `grep postgres` in the output, it's not running.

Since you installed PostgreSQL with Homebrew, try `brew info postgres` for information on how to start up the server if that is indeed the case.

Comment: I'm sure this was, at least, two problems. One related with the postgreSQL not being connected. Another related with the Role (or user) that should be the same as the one on mac os. I'm still not sure, however, if I'm connected to the right postGreSQL :/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify a socket. Here's a configuration that works for Postgres. You only need to change the database password.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: testblog_development
  template: template0
```

Comment: Error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: btw, I have pool set as 5, not 5432, HOWEVER, the error stills displays 5432!! How weird can we get here ? :s

Comment: You should try that. Try connecting through the console: `sudo -u postgres psql`

Comment: sudo: unknown user: postgres - how can I see the list of default users ?

Comment: alfonso. It was a user issue. For some reason we should place the make user while not creating a new user specifically.

Comment: Please also note that in order to initialize the postgreSQL I HAD to download this 58MB of this elephant to make it start. http://postgresapp.com/ - otherwise, the error would keep coming.

Comment: Presumably the root problem is that the homebrew postgresql server was not running and you "solved" it by downloading and launching a different postgresql package instead of launching the one from homebrew.

Comment: @MEM based on your previous comment, I don't believe this answer actually solved your problem, like DanielVérité mentions.

Comment: @theIV perhaps. @Daniel Vérité I've done `which postgres` and, I believe, I'm getting the `path` of the one related with homebrew. So, I'm assuming that the problem was related with the fact that: 1) I didn't have a connection. 2) The user (role) wasn't the correct one. May I be wrong ?

Comment: @DanielVérité actually, when I do `brew info postgres`and I do the commands to start the server, I get no error, but I still can't connect. :(